# Why upcasting does not show runtime polymorphism?

Tags: java, polymorphism

I wrote a code to understand runtime polymorphism...

```
class S{
     int i=1;
    void m(){
        System.out.println("sssssssssssssssssssss");
    }
}
public class A extends S{

    int i=2;

    void m(){
        System.out.println("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        S a=(S)new A();
        System.out.println(a.i);
        a.m();
    }
}
```

Instance variable are subject to compile time binding, but why down casting of object of `A` does not meaning here? Means it's invoking `A's` method not `S's` method?

Comment: There is no downcasting happening here.

Comment: When you down cast the reference you don't change the object referenced.

Comment: @RohitJain I am new to java, but i thing i tried to cast A into S, and S is supertype of A.? Is the terminology of downcasting is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
S a = (S)new A();
```

Let's see what you have here:

1. variable `a`, of the *reference type* `S`;
2. an instance creation expression yielding an object of type `A`, where `A extends S`;
3. a *reference upcast expression*, upcasting the above expression into type `S`;
4. the assignment of the result of 3. into the variable `a`.

What you must keep clear in your mind when reading Java is the distinction between:

- the *type of the object*: an object can never change its type. In your example, the object is of type `A`;
- the *type of the reference*: in your example, you converted a reference initially of type `A` into a reference of type `S`. You assigned that reference to `a`.

When you invoke a method on an object, the actual method invoked does not at all depend on the type of the *reference*, but only on the type of the *object* itself. The type of your object is `A` therefore the method in type `A` is invoked.

On the other hand, when you access an instance variable, polymorphism does not apply and the type of the reference becomes essential. With `a.i` you access `i` declared in the supertype `S`, and with `((A)a).i` you access `i` from `A`. Note that the class `A` posseses *two* instance variables, both named `i`, and you can refer to each individually.

---

#### A note on terminology

The term "type of a reference" is actually a shorthand for the more correct "type of the expression yielding the reference." It is a purely compile-time artifact: there is no type information associated with a reference at runtime, it's just a bit pattern. Contrast this with the type of the object, which is a purely *runtime* artifact: the compiler doesn't in general know the type of the object involved in an expression, it only makes *assertions* about it. When such an assertion fails at runtime,  the result is a ClassCastException.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `a` is a reference of type `S` to an object whose class is `A`.  When you call `m()` on that object, you'll always get the version of `m()` in class `A` being called, because that's the class of the object, no matter what type of variable is referencing it.  That's what polymorphism is about.  The version of `m()` that gets called depends on the **class of the object**, not the **type of the referring expression**.

However, this object actually contains two variables called `i` - one declared in class `A` and the other in class `S`.  Which one of these you get depends on the **type of the referring expression** that you use.  Since the variable `a` is of type `S`, the expression `a.i` refers to the one that is declared in class `S`.

Comment: I think it would be better to clarify your terminology a bit - the variable isn't a reference; the *value* of the variable is a reference. The variable has a type; I wouldn't like to talk about the type of a reference, as that seems to pave the way to ambiguity. I find it clearer to talk about the compile-time type of an expression (a variable in this case, but not always) vs the execution-time type of the object that the expression's value refers to.

Comment: @JonSkeet I find the conflation of *object type* with *reference type* to be an important source of misunderstanding. The type of a `String` variable is something completely disparate from the type of a `String` instance.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: I wouldn't talk about the "reference type" here, to be honest. I'd talk about the object type vs the variable type. I think of references themselves as being untyped, in a way - it only makes sense to talk about the expression you used to get a reference, or the type of the object that the reference refers to (which you can only discover by following the reference).

Comment: @JonSkeet If we constrain ourselves to variable type, we get into difficulty explaining the meaning of something like `( (A)getS() ).i` because there are no variables involved.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Then I'd use *expression* type. There are plenty of expressions there. And I'd make it clear which is compile-time and which is execution-time. I still wouldn't talk about the type of a reference.

Comment: @JonSkeet Fair point. In fact, variable type is only indirectly relevant as defining the expression type. However, the wording gets even more convoluted when you talk about *expressions* which *evaluate to references to objects* etc.

Comment: Thank you @JonSkeet - I thought about your points today, when a very similar question was asked.  You are absolutely right, and I have updated my answer accordingly.