# How to cast to run superclass method

Tags: java

Is there a way to use casting so the `m1()` method is run in `I1` class to print `In I1 class`? I don't want it to run the overridden method.

```
class TestClass extends I1 implements I2{
       public void m1() { System.out.println("Hello"); }
       public static void main(String[] args){
          I1 tc = new TestClass();
          tc.m1();
       }
    }
    class I1{
       int VALUE = 1;
       public void m1(){System.out.println("In I1 class");}
    }
    interface I2{
       int VALUE = 2;
       void m1();
    }
```

Comment: I thought ((I1)tc).m1(); would work, but it still prints "Hello"

Comment: No, that would be big security flaw. Similar question explaining why `super.super` is also impossible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586363/why-is-super-super-method-not-allowed-in-java

Comment: You can't do that. [Here][1] is the explanation why.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22874698/4228138

Comment: @MateuszKorwel Nice find. Anyway if you want to post links in comments simply use `[description](link)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do this. Part of the point of polymorphism is to be able to hide implementation detail from classes lower down in the hierarchy. You can invoke the superclass method, but only as a call inside the overridden method.

Think about it like this. Maybe `TestClass` does something important inside method `m1` that maintains its internal state and keeps it consistent. Perhaps it tracks something that's done in the superclass, and maintains its own cache, or copy, or similar. If you could make it invoke the superclass method, that code wouldn't get run, and you'd break `TestClass` badly.

The reason that the suggestion in your comment

```
((I1)tc).m1();
```

doesn't work is that you've changed the *formal* type but not the *actual* type. Invocation of overridden methods is based on the *actual* type, at runtime, so the JVM will still notice that this is of type `TestClass`, and invoke the overridden method.

Answer (score 0):

You first declared `I1 tc = new TestClass()`, so even you do `((I1)tc).m1()`, `tc` is still pointing to an object of `TestClass()`. Thats why it wouldn't work.

If you want to call `m1()` from the `I1` class, you should do `I1 tc = new I1();` instead.