# Inheriting a FINAL field and casting subclass object into parent class to use it

Tags: java, inheritance, final

```
class Test {
public static final String FOO = "foo";
public static void main(String[] args) {
Test b = new Test();
Sub s = new Sub();
System.out.print(Test.FOO);           /* Prints foo */
System.out.print(Sub.FOO);            /* Prints bar */
System.out.print(b.FOO);              /* Prints foo */
System.out.print(s.FOO);              /* Prints bar */
 System.out.print(((Test)s).FOO);     /* Prints foo but Why?*/ 
 } }
 class Sub extends Test {public static final String FOO="bar";}
```

I was reading about Inheritance and i found out that even when you cast a SUB CLASS object to PARENT class and try to call a overridden method using that object (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874640/overriding-methods-in-java-and-then-casting-object-to-parent-class-behavior)), the SUBCLASS method will be called.

But here in my Question why the Parent Class variable value is being printed even when the object TYPE is of Class Sub.?

Comment: `final static` variables can not be overridden

Comment: Yes , you are right. But why does the last System.out.print prints "foo" not bar.?

Comment: because that is the value of the parent class, which can not be overridden

Comment: Ok. But in case of methods because they can be overridden, it goes down to TYPE OF OBJECT rather than the reference. Right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Static members are resolved by the type of the expression that is used to reference it, if you use `<expression>.staticMember`.

In this case `((Test)s)` is an expression of type `Test` and this is why `Test.FOO` is referenced in `((Test)s).FOO`.

Note that it's bad practice to use instances to reference static members, since this just leads to confusion. Always using `<ClassName>.staticMember` avoids this kind of confusion, i.e. use

```
Test.FOO
```

or

```
Sub.FOO
```

Comment: That Cleared by doubt. Thanks.!