# Difrences between changing layout background color in java

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm a newbie to the android development.
I have two approaches to change the layout background color via Java. Which one could be more appropriate and why?

The first approach is:

```java
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.translation_container);
layout.setBackgroundColor(mColor);
```

and the second one:

```java
View view = convertView.findViewById(R.id.translation_container);
int color = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),mColor);
view.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

Comment: `translation_container` is a LinearLayout which is located into another LinearLayout. Since it's LinearLayout, why should I assign it into `View`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for one there is something very wrong between the two, and that is the fact that you are calling `ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), mColor)` with one and directly `setBackgroundColor(mColor)` on the other.

[`ContextCompat.getColor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#getColor(android.content.Context,%20int)) is supposed to be called with a color resource ID, ie. a `R.color.value`. It returns the color value from your resources that corresponds to that resource ID.

Depending on what you have in the value of ```mColor''', there is a good chance that one of these options is not setting the correct color you are expecting.

If `mColor` is a color resource ID, then the second one is correct. If `mColor` is the color you want to set, then the first is correct.

When it comes to the cast you are doing into a `LinearLayout` it is unnecessary. Both options call the same method [`View.setBackgroundColor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor(int)). You can go with `View` for now as the type of your view variable.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify about it, `mColor` gets its value from resource.
Why should one of them get its value from resource whereas other shouldn't?

Comment: Then your second option, which calls ContextCompat.getColor, is the one you want to use. Your first one is setting the background color to the value of the resource ID, you def do not want that.

Answer (score 0):

LinearLayout extends ViewGroup which extends View. So LinearLayout also a View.
So there is no difference between `View.setBackgroundColor()` and `LinearLayout.setBackgroundColor()`. LinearLayout did not override this method.

See [View.setBackgroundColor()](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#L20286)

See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html

Comment: Alternate universe; even if LinearLayout overrides setBackgroundColor, a LinearLayout cast as a View will call the overridden method. Basis of polymorphism -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874640/overriding-methods-in-java-and-then-casting-object-to-parent-class-behavior