# UpCasting and DownCasting Java accessing methods

Tags: java, computer-science, upcasting

I am unable to understand upcasting and the accessing of methods. I have read through multiple other questions on a similar understanding problem I am having but I still can not understand. I am hoping that a more personalized answer to my question could help me understand it better.

My problem with upcasting is that I've learned from my computer science class that when an child object is upcasted to an parent class it just is labeled something else, because it is labeled something else it is unable to call methods from the child class.

This is there explanation:
"Cats can’t purr, while being labeled something else
If you upcast an object it will lose all its properties which were inherited from below its current  position. For example, if you cast a Cat to an Animal, it will lose properties inherited from  Mammal and Cat. Note, that data will not be lost you just can't use it until you downcast the  object to the right level.
Why is it like that? If you have a group of Animals, then you can't be sure which ones can  meow() and which ones can bark(). That is why you can't make Animal do things that are only  specific for Dogs or Cats."

This explanation makes sense to me but when I tested it in this code:

```
public class SchoolMember 
{
    public void schoolDay() 
    {
    System.out.print(“School open”); 
    } 
}

public class Teacher extends SchoolMember  
{  
    public void schoolDay()  
    {  
    System.out.print(“Teachers teaching”);  
    }  
}  

public class TeacherAide extends Teacher 
{ 
    public void schoolDay() 
    { 
    System.out.print(“Students learning”); 
    } 
}

public class Main(){
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SchoolMember person1 = new SchoolMember(); 
        Teacher person2 = new Teacher();
        TeacherAide person3 = new TeacherAide();
        person2 = (Teacher) person3;
        person1.schoolDay();
        person2.schoolDay();
    }
}
```

The output of this code is:
Schools OpenStudentsLearning

but from my understanding the output of the code should be
Schools OpenTeachers teaching

Could somebody please help me with understanding this question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overriding methods in java and then casting object to parent class behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874640/overriding-methods-in-java-and-then-casting-object-to-parent-class-behavior)

Comment: `person3` is a cast of `TeacherAide` and this implements the method `schoolDay()` as "students learning", even when you cast this to `Teacher` the method retains its output because the method is overriden in `TeacherAide`.

Comment: The explanation you have appears to refer to methods which are unique to the type and therefore not inherited, so when you upcast and object you can't call the child method because it doesn't exist for the parent.

Comment: It is a common pattern in object oriented programming to assign concrete classes to their interface or abstract types (i.e. parent types). This allows for freedom later when the code is required to be changed. Parent classes are often"contracts" that the child classes implement, so detail is abstracted.

In your example, you are invoking `person2` of type `Teacher`. That is the parent type, although you know the object held is the child "TeacherAide", the compiler doesn't until you cast `person2`. Therefore if you do: `((TeacherAide) person2).schoolDay()` - you'll get what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is part of a OO concept called Polymorphism.
The explanation you reported is correct, but I understand that it can be a bit complex.
I think there's a simpler way to say it (and to keep it simple I will use as little technical terms as possible).

Let's introduce **handles and objects**.

An object is something you create with the *new* keyword, and has an address in your computer's memory. An object is an *instance* of a class, so for example you have a *single* `Teacher` class but can create *any number* of `Teacher` objects, each one using the *new* keyword (e.g. `new Teacher()`).
Each `Teacher` object contains it's own copy of non-static fields and non-static methods. **EACH ONE**

An handle, on the other side, is simply a pointer to an object. In Java you can define an handle simply using `Classname handlename`, (e.g. `Teacher myTeacher`).
An handle carries no information, it just points to a specific object in memory or to `null`.
So when you in your code perform the following statement:

`person2 = (Teacher) person3;`

you are just saying *"let the handle **person2** point to the same object pointed by the handle **person3**"*. But from the previous line we **know** that person3 points to a *`TeacherAide` instance*, so now also person2 points to that very same instance!
So if you now call `person2.schoolDay()` you are calling the `schoolDay()` method of that `TeacherAide` object, which of course prints "Students learning"...

BTW, the `(Teacher)` cast is useless, since `person3` is an handle to `TeacherAide`, which is a subclass of `Teacher`, so itself can be viewed as a `Teacher` without any explicit cast.
In other words: a `TeacherAide` is always a `Teacher` (in your model), while not every `Teacher` is a `TeacherAide`. Hence the need for explicit cast *only when downcasting*.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation you quoted is quite correct. However, does not directly apply to your example.
In your case you are extending the class `SchoolMember` and overriding its method `schoolDay()`.
Thus you can still call the method `schoolDay()` without any compilation error. Meanwhile, being any method invoked dynamically according to the actual type of the object you're still calling the overridden method.

The following example, instead, would generate an error due to upcasting:

```
public class SchoolMember 
{
    public void schoolDay() {
        System.out.print(“School open”); 
    } 
}

public class Teacher extends SchoolMember  
{  
    public void newMethod(){  
        System.out.print(“Teachers teaching”);  
    }  
}

public class Main(){
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SchoolMember person1; 
        Teacher person2 = new Teacher();
        person1 = (SchoolMember) person2;
        person1.newMethod(); \\ Error even if you are referring to a Teacher object
    }
}
```